# Implicit conversion of datatypes from varchar2 to date, number etc

Tags: oracle

Say I have some columns that are currently varchar2 values, in a table Table_A.

Given that they are the correct format for date (formatted through an update statement with to_date), and I want to insert data from Table_A that has the original varchar2 values, into Table_B which has corresponding Date columns - will Oracle do the conversion from varchar2 to Date implicitly, if the date format is correct?

Likewise, I wonder if Oracle would convert a decimal number stored as Varchar2 to a Number(N,M) with the corresponding correct format in the target table.

The reason I am asking, is to see if I can avoid writing large queries that have to first switch column types before doing the select and then insert into target table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, it's all about `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.
But there is risk:

```
create table a(
  pk integer not null,
  dt varchar2(30)
);
create table b(
  pk integer not null,
  dt date
);
--
-- This example shows date truncation because of the nls_date_format
--
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY';
insert into b values(1, sysdate);
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from b;
-- 2021-02-02 11:53:05
insert into a select * from b;
select * from a;
-- 02-FEB-2021
delete b;
insert into b select * from a;
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from b;
-- 2021-02-02 00:00:00

--
-- This example shows a working conversion
---
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
delete a;
delete b;
insert into b values(1, sysdate);
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from b;
-- 2021-02-02 11:53:05
insert into a select * from b;
select * from a;
-- 2021-02-02 11:53:05
delete b;
insert into b select * from a;
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from b;
-- 2021-02-02 11:53:05

--
-- This example shows a failure because of bad date mask.
--
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';
delete a;
delete b;
insert into b values(1, sysdate);
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') dt from b;
-- 2021-02-02 11:53:05
insert into a select * from b;
select * from a;
-- 2021-02-02
alter session set nls_date_format='Dy DD/MM HH24:MI:SS';
delete b;
insert into b select * from a;
-- ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week
```

In short, don't do it unless absolutely necessary.
If you have to do it, make sure you control `nls_date_mask` by setting it in your script prior to the SQL execution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easier for numbers - as long as the decimal separator is consistent across all tables and columns. If a column in one table has the format `33.29` and a column in another table has the format `33,29` for the same thing - because it uses comma as the decimal separator - you will have problems.

For dates it will be a bit more complicated - especially if some dates are like `'12/31/2020'` and others are like `'12/31/2020 00:00:00'`.

If all numbers are in the exact same format, and if all dates are in the exact same format, it should work; for dates, you will need to make sure that `nls_date_format` is the same format as your strings (or change it with `alter session`), and for numbers you must make sure that `nls_numeric_characters` shows the same decimal separator (and, if used, the same grouping separator) as your numeric strings.

I might do what you are suggesting for "play" databases (for testing, for example) - or in an environment where you can't do too much damage. I wouldn't do this in production, if non-trivial things depend on the database and the data in it.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I wanted to hear :) I have updated the format of the date and numbers to be corresponding to the target table format, as well as the NLS - just wanted to know if this was enough, or if I had to take the long route of copying to new intermittent columns before selecting and inserting. I will try as you suggest, and do an initial trial to see if it works. Many thanks!